# Single Sign On(SSO) using SAML with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I done my 2 projects(i.e web portals) using spring mvc + hibernate with JAVA. MySQL as db and Apache as server.
Now my requirement is to get SSO(Single Sign On) for these two Portals. i previously posted about this but only one person responded.
Again i google and got SAML extension. And i got some sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml .
And followed this https://docs.secureauth.com/display/docs/Spring+Security+Instructions to get SSO for my portals.

I just integrated only one portal with the  procedure given in above link.
**In the above link of process i didn't understood secureAuth20.xml and Post auth.**

But i stuck getting the error on web page when i run on server.
ERROR:

Error

An error occurred.
Message:
Metadata for entity localhost and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor wasn't found 
StackTrace:

org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Metadata for entity http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/ and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor wasn't found

in Consloe of my STS :

- Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Feb 11 14:10:34 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
- Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml]

**securityContext.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

  <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
  <context:annotation-config/>

  <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
     <context:component-scan 
    base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

 <!-- Unsecured pages -->
 <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
 <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
 <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
 <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

  <!-- Security for the administration UI -->
   <security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" 
     access-denied-page="/saml/web/metadata/login">
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-
       page="/saml/web/metadata/login" 
      default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" 
   access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" 
     ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
  </security:http>

   <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
  <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" 
   access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST"   
  ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
  </security:http>

  <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
  <bean id="samlFilter" 
 class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" 
 filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" 
  filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" 
 filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" 
 filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" 
 filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" 
  filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" 
 filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
   </bean>

 <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
 <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.
     SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
 </bean>
   <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
  <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.
 SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.jsp"/>
   </bean>

  <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
  <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class=   
    "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.   
   SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
    </bean>

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities 
     ="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

   <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
  <bean id="samlLogger" class= 
   "org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
   <bean id="keyManager" class=  
    "org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken  
   from properties file -->
   <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class= 
   "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class=     
   "org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
   <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" 
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security  
   /idpSelection.jsp"/>
     </bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
  <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class= 
  "org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class=
  "org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean class="     
     org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
   </bean>

   <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with 
  filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
  <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class=    
  "org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

   <!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle 
 of trust is here -->
<bean id="metadata" class=
    "org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <!-- IDP metadata -->
        <bean  class="     
  org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="    
  org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                    <constructor-arg value="/metadata/idp.xml"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
        </bean>
        <!-- SP metadata -->
        <bean class="  
 org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class=" 
 org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="
  org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                            <constructor-arg value="/metadata
      /localhost_sp.xml"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="  
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="local" value="true"/>
                    <property name="alias" value="localhost"/>
                    <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                    <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                    <property name="sslHostnameVerification" 
     value="allowAll"/>
                    <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                    <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" 
     value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" 
      value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" 
      value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </list>
 </constructor-arg>
   <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains
    information about this service provider -->
   <property name="hostedSPName" value="localhost"/>
   <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used
    for authenticating user by default. -->
  <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:6060
   /AxisCustomer/"/>
   </bean>
  <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class= 
  "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after   
    login -->
      <!--
      <property name="userDetails" ref="bean" />
      -->
   </bean>

   <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
   <bean id="contextProvider" class=    
  "org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->

     <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" 
  class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" 
   ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" 
    ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
   <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class= 
      "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"  
   ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler"   
     ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
   </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
     <bean id="logoutHandler"
      class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>
  <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing 
    SAML messages -->
  <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class=    
  "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
   </bean>
   <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
  <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected toafter     
   successful global logout -->
  <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class= 
   "org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class=   
   "org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
   </bean>

  <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
 <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class=   
 "org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

 <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
  <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class=    
"org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>
<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class=    
   "org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>
  <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
  <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class=   
"org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

   <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
   <bean id="ecpprofile"    
  class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

   <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
   <bean id="logoutprofile" class    
  ="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>


    <bean id="postBinding" class    
    ="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class     
 ="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding
   ">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="artifactBinding"   
 class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class ="    
  org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl
  ">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class 
   ="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="processor">
                <bean 
   class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
       </constructor-arg>
       </bean>

   <bean id="soapBinding"   
  class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="paosBinding"    
 class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
   <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<bean id="velocityEngine"    
   class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" 
         factory-method="getEngine"/>
     <!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
  <bean id="parserPool"    
 class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" 
    init-method="initialize">
    <property name="builderFeatures">
        <map>
            <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-
     node-expansion" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>
   </bean>

<bean id="parserPoolHolder"    
 class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
 </beans>
```

**idp.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <EntityDescriptor entityID=
   "http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/" 
   xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"   
    protocolSupportEnumeration=
   "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
   MIICQDCCAakCBEeNB0swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQAwZzEL
 MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNh
  bGlmb3JuaWExFDASBgNVBAcTC1NhbnRhIENsYXJh
 MQwwCgYDVQQKEwNTdW4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB09w
 ZW5TU08xDTALBgNVBAMTBHRlc3QwHhcNMDgwMTE1MT
  kxOTM5WhcNMTgwMTEyMTkxOTM5WjBnMQsw
 CQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZv
 cm5pYTEUMBIGA1UEBxMLU2FudGEgQ2xhcmExDDAK
 BgNVBAoTA1N1bjEQMA4GA1UECxMHT3BlblNTTzE
  NMAsGA1UEAxMEdGVzdDCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
  AQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEArSQc/U75GB2AtKhbGS5pii
  LkmJzqEsp64rDxbMJ+xDrye0EN/q1U5Of+
  RkDsaN/igkAvV1cuXEgTL6RlafFPcUX7QxDhZBhs
  YF9pbwtMzi4A4su9hnxIhURebGEmxKW9qJNY
  Js0Vo5+IgjxuEWnjnnVgHTs1+mq5QYTA7E6ZyL8
  CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFAAOBgQB3Pw/U
QzPKTPTYi9upbFXlrAKMwtFf2OW4yvGWWvlcwcNS
   ZJmTJ8ARvVYOMEVNbsT4OFcfu2/PeYoAdiDA
  cGy/F2Zuj8XJJpuQRSE6PtQqBuDEHjjmOQJ0rV/
  r8mO1ZCtHRhpZ5zYRjhRC9eCbjx9VrFax0JDC
 /FfwWigmrW0Y0Q==
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <ArtifactResolutionService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding=
   "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location=
  "http://localhost:8080/opensso/ArtifactResolver/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding=
  "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location=
  "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp" 
  ResponseLocation=
    "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding=
 "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location=
 "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp"   
 ResponseLocation=
   "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleLogoutService 
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" 
  Location="http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPSloSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <ManageNameIDService 
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" 
 Location="http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp"  
ResponseLocation=
  "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <ManageNameIDService     
  Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location=
 "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp" 
 ResponseLocation=
  "http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <ManageNameIDService 
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" 
 Location="http://localhost:8080/opensso/IDPMniSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-
  format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-
   format:transient</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
   format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
   format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding=
 "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location=
 "http://localhost:8080/opensso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleSignOnService 
 Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location=
 "http://localhost:8080/opensso/SSOSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <NameIDMappingService 
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location=
  "http://localhost:8080/opensso/NIMSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <AssertionIDRequestService    
 Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location=
 "http://localhost:8080/opensso/AIDReqSoap/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <AssertionIDRequestService 
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:URI" 
Location=
 "http://localhost:8080/opensso/AIDReqUri/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp"/>
</IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

**localhost_sp.xml**(downloaded entity)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md=
    "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="localhost" 
   entityID="localhost">
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
 <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=
 "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod    
Algorithm=
     "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference 
  URI="#localhost"><ds:Transforms>
  <ds:Transform Algorithm=
       "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm=
  "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
 <ds:DigestValue>AvF5jq5CC2Hj8GIoGUZ5DYcVcoE=</ds:DigestValue>    
    </ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo>
 <ds:SignatureValue>Jfn6P9Hqp/SKHOQE5MCrjY4Fp7kbJsSZOafCVS5beB
   VOuyCvSyTyrMFD5Xx5x0qw6TZSQuG9OFZPEC
  T4Sv9fU5cPTQIrxNv7jx88ie8GCjllypaYIaGPn
  3YxY819aiilGL/1x4TgSkWsVJUIH8i1iBjYIPnU6rXr0uEO1J
   nft2T6uz8tUc01QCliscnNsOhU0ffYcjR
  \ApI3tzZxgjR8A5vSDJHphbOScizR
  IyXVD8sZfW1d0shtVkFjVYjl6ek4H
    9Znlb7J0iHUqT3dqwaB+Y6IMFM8zA+aQGHVoT
 36UVyTuifq7IDqGZzQVPYEmOl1jy/3dYeLIcPiGCW+rgmhZ1w==
  </ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>
  MIIDUjCCAjqgAwIBAgIEUOLIQTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBrMQswCQYDV            
   QTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBrMQswCQYDV       
      QQGEwJGSTEQMA4GA1UE
      CBMHVXVzaW1hYTERMA8GA1UEBxMISGVsc2lua
   2kxGDAWBgNVBAoTD1JNNSBTb2Z0d2FyZSBPeTEM
   MAoGA1UECwwDUiZEMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZhcG9s
   bG8wHhcNMTMwMTAxMTEyODAxWhcNMjIxMjMwMTEy
   ODAxWjBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJGSTEQMA4GA1UECB
   MHVXVzaW1hYTERMA8GA1UEBxMISGVsc2lua2kx
   GDAWBgNVBAoTD1JNNSBTb2Z0d2FyZSBPeTEMMAoGA1
   UECwwDUiZEMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZhcG9sbG8w
   ggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBA
   QCXqP0wqL2Ai1haeTj0alwsLafhrDtUt00E
   5xc7kdD7PISRA270ZmpYMB4W24Uk2QkuwaBp6dI/
   yRdUvPfOT45YZrqIxMe2451PAQWtEKWF5Z13
  F0J4/lB71TtrzyH94RnqSHXFfvRN8EY/
  rzuEzrpZrHdtNs9LRyLqcRTXMMO4z7QghBuxh3K5gu7K
 qxpHx6No83WNZj4B3gvWLRWv05nbXh/F9YMe
 QClTX1iBNAhLQxWhwXMKB4u1iPQ/KSaal3R26pON
 UUmu1qVtU1quQozSTPD8HvsDqGG19v2+/
   N3uf5dRYtvEPfwXN3wIY+/R93vBA6lnl5nTctZIRsyg
    0Gv5AgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAFQwAAY
   Ujso1VwjDc2kypK/RRcB8bMAUUIG0hLGL
  82IvnKouGixGqAcULwQKIvTs6uGmlgbSG6Gn5ROb2ml
     BztXqQ49zRvi5qWNRttir6eyqwRFGOM6A
   8rxj3Jhxi2Vb/MJn7XzeVHHLzA1sV5hwl/
    2PLnaL2h9WyG9QwBbwtmkMEqUt/dgixKb1Rvby/tBu
       RogWgPONNSACiW+Z5o8UdAOqNMZQozD/
    i1gOjBXoF0F5OksjQN7xoQZLj9xXefxCFQ69FPcFDeEW
bHwSoBy5hLPNALaEUoa5zPDwlixwRjFQTc5XXaRpgIjy/2gsL8+Y5QRhyXnLqgO67BlLYW
      /GuHE=            
        </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor>         
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
       <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds=
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDUjCCAjqgAwIBAgIEUOLI
         QTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBrMQswCQYDV       
      QQGEwJGSTEQMA4GA1UE
      CBMHVXVzaW1hYTERMA8GA1UEBxMISGVsc2lua
   2kxGDAWBgNVBAoTD1JNNSBTb2Z0d2FyZSBPeTEM
   MAoGA1UECwwDUiZEMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZhcG9s
   bG8wHhcNMTMwMTAxMTEyODAxWhcNMjIxMjMwMTEy
   ODAxWjBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJGSTEQMA4GA1UECB
   MHVXVzaW1hYTERMA8GA1UEBxMISGVsc2lua2kx
   GDAWBgNVBAoTD1JNNSBTb2Z0d2FyZSBPeTEMMAoGA1
   UECwwDUiZEMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZhcG9sbG8w
   ggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBA
   QCXqP0wqL2Ai1haeTj0alwsLafhrDtUt00E
   5xc7kdD7PISRA270ZmpYMB4W24Uk2QkuwaBp6dI/
   yRdUvPfOT45YZrqIxMe2451PAQWtEKWF5Z13
  F0J4/lB71TtrzyH94RnqSHXFfvRN8EY/
  rzuEzrpZrHdtNs9LRyLqcRTXMMO4z7QghBuxh3K5gu7K
 qxpHx6No83WNZj4B3gvWLRWv05nbXh/F9YMe
 QClTX1iBNAhLQxWhwXMKB4u1iPQ/KSaal3R26pON
 UUmu1qVtU1quQozSTPD8HvsDqGG19v2+/
   N3uf5dRYtvEPfwXN3wIY+/R93vBA6lnl5nTctZIRsyg
    0Gv5AgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAFQwAAY
   Ujso1VwjDc2kypK/RRcB8bMAUUIG0hLGL
  82IvnKouGixGqAcULwQKIvTs6uGmlgbSG6Gn5ROb2ml
     BztXqQ49zRvi5qWNRttir6eyqwRFGOM6A
   8rxj3Jhxi2Vb/MJn7XzeVHHLzA1sV5hwl/
    2PLnaL2h9WyG9QwBbwtmkMEqUt/dgixKb1Rvby/tBu
       RogWgPONNSACiW+Z5o8UdAOqNMZQozD/
    i1gOjBXoF0F5OksjQN7xoQZLj9xXefxCFQ69FPcFDeEW
bHwSoBy5hLPNALaEUoa5zPDwlixwRjFQTc5XXaRpgIjy/2gsL8+Y5QRhyXnLqgO67BlLYW
      /GuHE=            
  </ds:X509Certificate>
       </ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor>
     <md:SingleLogoutService Binding=
      "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location=
    "http://localhost/saml/SingleLogout/alias/localhost"/> 
   <md:SingleLogoutService Binding=
     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-    
   Redirect" Location=
        "http://localhost/saml/SingleLogout/alias/localhost"/>
     <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
 format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat> 
   <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-
     format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-
 format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
 <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
  format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid- 
  format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat><md:AssertionConsumerService 
   Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"    
  Location="http://localhost/saml/SSO/alias/localhost" index="0" 
  isDefault="true"/></md:SPSSODescriptor></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Please suggest your suggestions to resolve .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

The error means that Spring SAML has received a SAML message issued by IDP with entity ID "http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/", but it can't find any such entity in your available metadata. Make sure that your metadata bean contains an entity with this ID. Or just attach all your metadata documents and I can have a look.

I suggest you use the following metadata definition:

```
<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<bean id="metadata" class=
        "org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <!-- IDP metadata -->
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                        <constructor-arg value="/metadata/idp.xml"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            <!-- SP metadata -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/metadata/localhost_sp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="local" value="true"/>
                        <property name="alias" value="localhost"/>
                        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="allowAll"/>
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                        <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains
    information about this service provider -->
    <property name="hostedSPName" value="localhost"/>
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used
     for authenticating user by default. -->
    <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/"/>
</bean>
```

Make sure that the referenced idp.xml file is in the /metadata/idp.xml in your project (you should already have a file named localhost_sp.xml there) and that the entity ID in your idp.xml is http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/

Comment: The metadata in your idp.xml has entity ID http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomerImageDone/ while the message you receive is issued by http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/. You need to make sure that the entity IDs are consistent. One thing you can try is to simply rename the entityID in the idp.xml to http://localhost:6060/AxisCustomer/ Please note that Stackoverlow is stripping the http part of the URL, make sure to use the correct values

Comment: i kept the same url in idp and metadat also... but still in web browser  Metadata for entity localhost and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor wasn't found  is coming... and in console : - Error retrieving metadata from http://AxisCustomer
java.net.UnknownHostException: AxisCustomer

Comment: i took the example in gitub of you. can you show me how to integrate SAML with some sample hello world(login) program with your github saml project.. because am a new bee, i want lot of things to learn from experience persons like you. please show how to integrate SAML with spring security,

Comment: i didn't understood that secureAuth Post authentication also. i stuck here from 7 days. i hope that you will sort out of my issue. so please show me by doing saml integration for a sample login program with your github project. so that i can learn and understand it..

Comment: Your metadata provider for IDP (HTTPMetadataProvider) is configured to load metadata from URL http://AxisCustomer, I believe that your environment doesn't provide any metadata there and that's the reason for both the UnknownHostException you see and the reason why SSO doesn't work. Make sure to either point to a correct URL, or use ResourceBackedMetadataProvider and use a file.

Comment: The easiest way to try the Spring SAML library out is to follow the steps in the quick start guide. Beyond that I'd recommend you to read the SAML specification which contains lot of explanations of the concepts involving federations.

Comment: i followed the quick start guid as u suggested. i imported sample diretory of spring security saml in github. . after i imported the sample and updated maven and run the project on server. it is perfectly running in the server and in web page i selected radio button and clicked on start sign on. it is redirected to another page and in that page SAML error it is shown instead of login, new user e.t.c.

Comment: Error in web page is 

Error occurred

Reason: The SAML Request is invalid.

Comment: now i followed again quick start guide of saml . i registered in online demo application. and am pastig the meta data in new service provider. error is coming as Meta Data Import

Your data could not be imported
Reason:



A http://localhost:6060/spring-security-saml2-sample entity already exists. Go to the Federation tab, and delete the existing http://localhost:6060/spring-security-saml2-sample entity. Then you can return to reconfigure it.

Comment: The guide tells you to change the entity ID of your Service Provider in the metadata generator filter to a unique value. You have not performed this step before generating your SP metadata and importing it to SSO Circle.

Comment: i had changed the value oh that entity id... but still its coming same error

Comment: the answer posted by you.when i run that by replacing by your suggested code in console: Signature verification failed.
- Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry localhost
- Error filtering metadata from file:/D:springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/SamlSample/WEB-INF/classes/metadata/localhost_sp.xml
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilterException: Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry . in web page Message:
Metadata for entity localhost and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor wasn't found

Comment: Either don't sign your own SP metadata, or disable metadata signature checking by setting property metadataTrustCheck on ExtendedMetadataDelegate of the provider bean you use to import the local SP metadata. And again, the quick start guide doesn't say anything about creating localhost_sp.xml, it's using automatically generated metadata, so you're not following the instructions there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475392/spring-saml-sample-application please go through this link. i wanna do this from Scratch

Comment: when i done the saml from scrach using quick start guid following error coming Meta Data Import

Your data could not be imported
Reason:



A http://localhost:6060/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/metadata entity already exists. Go to the Federation tab, and delete the existing http://localhost:6060/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/metadata entity. Then you can return to reconfigure it.

Comment: In the quick start guide there are instructions to change the entity ID of your application to a unique value - "make sure to replace the entityId value with a string which is unique within the SSO Circle service (e.g. urn:test:yourname:yourcity)". You have not done that.

Comment: u mean FQDN? or i have to change Entity Id in Sample program?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html#quick-start-sp-metadata

Comment: I receive the same Exception and reading my logs I f've found out a univoce char at the end of the IDP entity: <U+200B>. I cannot understand where it comes from

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue with my java8 and tomcat 8 setup . Upon checking i found out that i was missing a jar in tomcat libs folder "bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar" . Upon adding this jar , i didn't get this error any more

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had run into this problem as well where the IDP was using a different certificate for the SSL/TLS connection used to **refresh** the metadata and the certificate that was being used to **sign** the payloads.  So the fix was to import both certificates.